# How I can delete (filter) object from embedded array?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, filter

I have a struct PetType embedded in the Pet and Ped embedded in the People. I need to remove all peoples with some PetType (filter). How I can use the filter to delete all peoples which I don't need and save the right the structure? I need peoples who have a pet with soft skin (as example)

```
struct People {
    let name: String
    let pets: [Pet]
}

struct Pet {
    let name: String
    let type: PetstType
}

struct PetstType {
    let isSoftSkin: Bool
}


let peoples: [People] = []
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? And what about people that has both?

Comment: I try to use people.map { people in people.map { pet in pet.filter { $0.isSoftSkin} } }. And the result was [[[PetsType]]]. But I need a save model.

Comment: Well add your attempt to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to keep only elements of an `Array` that match a specified criteria. Inside `filter`, you can call `contains(where:)` on the `pets` array, to check if any elements of the array match your criteria.

```
let filteredPeople = people.filter { person in person.pets.contains(where: { pet in pet.type.isSoftSkin }) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [removeAll(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017530-removeall), but to use it, the `peoples` array needs to be a `var`.

```
peoples.removeAll { $0.pets.contains(where: { pet in pet.type.isSoftSkin }) }
```